# Automatically switch to another Google account during work hours?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, automation

I have two Google accounts:

- personal@gmail.com
- business@company.com

Is it possible to automatically change between during working hours?

Example:

- Monday to Friday

  - 08:00 - 17:00 -> business@company.com
- Every other time -> personal@gmail.com

Perhaps with Tampermonkey or something?

Comment: Another approach is to use different web browser profiles for each "web browsing mode". Have you considered this?

Answer (score 1):

tampermonkey won't do due to safety issues...

but you can try this extension: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/account-switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-account-switcher-for/mnannclpojfocmcjfhoicjbkjllajfhg?hl=en)** which is able to switch multiple accounts with a single click. and in case you are too lazy to even click you can automate it with **[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** where you can set an easy timer and fully automate your switch